# Salvar um grande formulário na database

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, formulário

Vamos supor que eu tenha um formulário grande, 30 campos que contendo `textareas`, `radio buttons`, `checkboxes`, `select tags`, etc.

Após o `submit` do formulário, qual seria a melhor maneira de pegar esses valores e depois salva-los no banco? A melhor prática, eu digo usar o menor número de linhas possíveis.

Eu faço deste jeito

```
$nome = $_POST['nome '];
$idade = $_POST['idade '];
$cidade = $_POST['cidade '];
```

e assim vai...

```
"UPDATE nome_tabela SET var1='$var1', var2='$var2', var3='$var3',...,'var30=$var30' WHERE id='$id'"
```

Deve-se haver uma maneira bem mais fácil de se fazer isso (talvez com um `foreach`). idéias, sugestões são todas bem vindas.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Em seu `HTML` use o `name` dos campos iguais ao nomes das colunas do seu banco de dados, por exemplo:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<label>Nome:</label>
<input type="text" name="nome" /> <!-- o nome da coluna do banco é nome -->
<label>Idade:</label>
<input type="text" name="idade" /> <!-- o nome da coluna do banco é idade -->
```

Após isso crie uma função para armazenar os dados usando o laço de repetição `for`

```
/*
* $tabela é o nome da tabela onde sera salvo os dados
* $dados é o valor passado pelo POST via formulario
*/
public function salvar($tabela, $dados) 
{
foreach($dados as $campo => $valor) {
    $campos[] = $campo; // Criara um array com os nomes dos inputs
    $valores[] = "'$valor'"; // Criara um array com os valores dos inputs
}

$campos = implode(',', $campos); // Junta o array separando os nomes com virgula
$valores = implode(',', $valores); // Junta o array separando os valores com virgula
}
```

Esta funcao ira gerar os nomes dos campos e os valores dos campos separados por virgula, ficaram assim;

```
$campo = "nome, idade" e  $valores = "'joao', '25'";
```

Agora é só montar sua query.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $tabela($campos) VALUES($valores)";
```

> Para chamar a função faça um `if` no arquivo onde se encontra o
>   formulario, de preferencia acima do `form`

```
if($_POST){ salvar('Tabela_x', $_POST); }
```

Answer (score 1):

A melhor prática é não tentar fazer no menor número de linhas possível, mas sim do jeito mais legível e fácil de dar manutenção, e principalmente, segura. Fazer uma solução inteligente demais (*clever*) pode prejudicar o código.

Você só deve sair do óbvio se houver um bom motivo. Você poderia, por exemplo, fazer um *loop* para montar o `UPDATE` se os nomes dos campos do formulário baterem com os nomes das colunas. Mas isto é inseguro, então não faça. Poderia criar um *array* , com os nomes das colunas. Mas não ajuda tanto. Você teria que limpar os dados propriamente ditos vindo de fora ou talvez usar um *prepared statement*, o que inviabilizaria esta "simplificação".

Lembrando que alguns dados precisam ser formatados antes de usar direto no banco de dados, então essa ideia do laço tem problemas demais para compensar.

Não faça temeridades, por exemplo permitir SQL Injection como está no seu código e que as outras respostas continuam fazendo.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dados = array("nome_da_coluna_nome" => $_POST['nome'],
               "nome_da_coluna_idade" => $_POST['idade'],
               "nome_da_coluna_cidade" => $_POST['cidade']);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nome_bd', 'usuario_bd', 'senha_bd');
$db->exec("set names utf8"); // opcional para codificação
$tabela = 'nome_da_tabela';

$campos = implode(", ", array_keys($dados));
$valores = "'".implode("','", array_values($dados))."'";
$resultado = $db->query("INSERT INTO `{$tabela}` ({$campos}) VALUES ({$valores})");
```